# Contact form is not working on my website

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I am trying to get my personal site updated and cannot figure out why my contact form is not working.  Here is the url to the page with the issue: http://zachjanice.com/#/contact

When I fill out the form there is no confirmation or rejection happening.  Inside of my contact.php file I have the following code:

```
<div class="midnight-blue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center animated fadeIn">
                <h1 class="page-header">Contact</h1>
                <p>Drop me a line and I will respond as quickly as possible.<br> Thank you for your interest.</p>
            </div><!-- col-md-8 -->
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- midnight-blue -->
<div class="clouds">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="contact">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 well">
                <form class="contactform" role="form" method="post" action="#/email.php">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label class="control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control " rows="4" cols="78" placeholder="Enter your message here" required></textarea>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">What is 2+2?</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Are you human?" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="controls" style="margin-left: 40%;">

                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="mybtn" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>

                    </div>
                </form>
                <?php
                    if ($_POST['submit']) {
                        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
                            if ($human == '4') {                 
                                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
                            } else { 
                                echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                            } 
                        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                            echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
                        }
                        } else {
                            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- clouds -->
```

In my email.php file which is placed in the root directory I have the following:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: zachjanice.com';
$to = 'zachjanice57@gmail.com';
$subject = 'From zachjanice.com';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

?>
```

I am very new to php so I don't know how to test it besides filling out the form.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm beyond flustered and need to get this site up.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have access to the server where you can look at the error logs? Turn on all error reporting and you will be able to see what the issue is.

Comment: Not working **HOW**? Not sending an email? You don't have a `mail()` call in the script that the form actually submits to, so the `mail()` call below your html is actually totally useless.

Comment: At the bottom of my contact.php page with all my html I have inside of the php if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                                echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>'; Is this not the correct place for this script?

Comment: I'm trying to follow a tutorial at this site: http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is generated via JavaScript, but starting out with a plain HTML form will help you figure the steps out faster. Client side validation via JavaScript is good, but you need server side PHP validation too. You need to beef up on form processing (don't worry, so do I!). You'll catch flack on this site about injection attacks and such. If you can, you may want to investigate some books on web application security. Here are some books that can get you started.

[PHP Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600656X)

[Web Application Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071776168)

You need a `<form>` tag that has the following inside it somewhere.

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
```

I found your opening `<form>` tag. Interesting.

```
<form class="contactform" role="form" method="post" action="#/email.php">
```

You may want to investigate your `action="#/email.php"` attribute a bit more. Is that what it's supposed to be?

I usually do something like this (HTML 4.01 inside of PHP. You are using HTML5) (where this line is generated via PHP). Note: Incomplete example.

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="contact.php" method="post">

</form>
```

In order for the following code to work, code *similar* to **email.php** must be called first so that the values are extracted from the `$_POST` superglobal array and stored in the variables that you use in contact.php ($name, $email, $human, $to, $subject, $body, $from). Otherwise, your form will, like you say, fail to contact you. This is a logic error, but you can fix it in no time if you find a good example.

No promises, but try this:

```
<?php

    require('email.php');  //Assuming it is in the same directory as your contact.php

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name !== '' && $email !== '') {  //Variables have not been extracted from $_POST yet, as in email.php
            if ($human === '4') {                 
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } else { 
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
            } 
        } elseif ($_POST['submit'] && $human !== '4') {
            echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

I might suggest a few resources to beef up on form processing.

[PHP Programming, 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449392776)

[Beginning PHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470413964)

[PHP, MySQL, & Apache: 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672335433)

[PHP Cookbook, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101015)

[PHP and MySQL Web Development: 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329166)

[Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, and CSS: Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319262)

Also, there are plenty of free tutorials on the web!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something strange:

```
<form class="contactform" role="form" method="post" action="#/email.php">
```

The `action` attribute has a `#` in front of the URL. There is no such URL on your site, and the # actually sort of breaks it. The resulting request of that form actually goes to your `/`; so `email.php` is never being called.

You may have meant to have `action="/email.php"` instead.